# How does the authentication process of applications via LDAP-directory works

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm new in LDAP. Perhaps the question may seem strange, but on the internet I have seen different versions. Please, help to understand which way is the correct authentication via LDAP. I have an LDAP-directory where user passwords are stored as hashes. I know two ways to authenticate third-party applications using the LDAP-directory:

1. Authentication check on the LDAP side. Using the “bind” function the DN and password of user are passed in plain-text. If the bind is successful user authenticate, otherwise doesn't.
2. Authentication check on the application side. Using the function “bind” we connect to the directory as an admin. We are looking for the right user and get his record. We parse password field, isolating the type of hash algorithm (e.g. {CRYPT}). We make hash of the user-entered password with proper algorithm. If the hashes are the same then the authentication is successful, otherwise not. (That is, the application must maintain an appropriate hash algorithm).

Which option is the most correct? And which way is considered a standard for any-vendor systems which claim support for LDAP-authentication?

Comment: Authorization or authentication? You've mentioned both. They aren't the same thing.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I mean authentication. The main question is how vendor systems (e.g. postfix, cisco wifi) use LDAP. I have one websphere application that works by the second approach and that is what confused me. I guess it is exception to the rule.

Comment: So please edit your quesiton and title accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use Option 1!!!!!

Option 2 has some disadvantages:

1. You'll need an admin account that can read the passwords to be able to compare them to the one you hashed. That means that the application is able to read the password hashed. I'd consider that a bad idea.
2. You'll circumvent additional security measurements implemented. The password you are checking might be the right one. But due to other policies the user might be locked and should not be able to login. And failed attempts will not count towards a possible lockout.
3. The hashing algorithm might change in future to one you haven't implemented yet.

You might be able to circumvent those obstacles but you will need aditional code to implement that. And that effort has already been taken and is readily availabel when you use option 1

Comment: I should add that you should use a secure LDAP-connection in any case to secure the transfered password!